# Merge polygons that are not intersecting using Clipper

Tags: c#, drawing, polygon, computational-geometry

I have a set of polygons which are not overlapping or intersecting each other, but they are placed exactly next to each other.
I would like to merge them into 1 polygon, only containing the perimeter path.
I have played around with the Clipper Library, to try to union them - but it doesn't seam to work, when they are not overlapping.

Any ideas how this could be done with Clipper (or any other C# solution)

The answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23365/combining-adjacent-polygons-sharing-a-similar-trait-into-1-polygon-arcgis) explains pretty well what I want.

Answer (score 2):

Merging polygons with collinear edges has had a major overhaul in Ver. 6 of Clipper. While this version hasn't been formally released yet (it's very close), it can still be downloaded from the [SF repository (trunk)](http://sourceforge.net/p/polyclipping/code/).

[image]
[image]
[image]